# Как принудительно обновить textArea в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим, у меня есть TextArea textArea (использую JavaFX).
И я хочу, чтобы сообщения в этом поле выходили с некоторой паузой между сообщениями.
То есть я делаю так:

```
textArea.appendText("A");
Thread.sleep(3000);
textArea.appendText("B");
```

Но по факту так не отрабатывает. Сначала проходит 3 секунды, после чего А и В добавляются одновременно.
Подозреваю, что так получается, потому что отрисовка ГУИ происходит в отдельном потоке.

Есть ли какой-то способ принудительно, "на лету", здесь и сейчас обновлять textArea прямо в коде после добавления первого сообщения? Возможно ли как-то, например, приостановить мейн поток до тех пор, пока ГУИ поток не отрисует первое сообщение, и только потом продолжать выполнение кода в мейн потоке?

Или какой ещё может быть способ решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае вы паузу делаете в том же потоке, в котором работает GUI, поэтому работа GUI блокируется на время паузы. Работу GUI не получится вынести в отдельный поток, поэтому наоборот нужно вынести кусок кода с задержкой в отдельный поток, изменения интерфейса делать через `Platform.runLater` (чтобы они выполнялись в основном потоке).

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("A"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return; // Поток прерван извне, просто завершить работу
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("B"));
});
thread.start();
```

Аналогично через `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("A"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("B"));
});
```