# Как запустить метод на фоне?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть алгоритм, который находит самый оптимальный вариант хода в определенный момент игры. На это уходит несколько секунд и в это время UI программы и все анимации замирают, как мне запустить метод так, что бы UI не замерзал?

Comment: Либо через Thread, либо через CompletableFuture, вот тут пример есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236892/1365

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @insolor, мне удалось решить проблему!

```
 public int moveRobot() {
    AtomicInteger move = new AtomicInteger();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        move.set(bestChoice());
        setSymbolOnBoard(move.get(), robot);
        System.out.println(move.get());
    });
    thread.start();
    return Integer.parseInt(move.toString());

}
```

Comment: У вас может `move` не успеть заполниться до его первого чтения в потоке запуска. Если вам нужен результат, то лучше `CompletableFuture`